# How to check PHP if statement without reloading page

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check a PHP if statement without reloading the page. 
I have a download page made with PHP ----.co m/download.php The page has a "Download" button, which downloads ----.co m/file.zip
The download page counts how many times the file has been downloaded and records it to a MySQL database. After a certain number of downloads on the file, I want the PHP to use copy() and replace the file with a new file. However, I don't want the user to have to visit ----.co m/download.php for the PHP to run the following:

```
else if ($fileInfos->downloads > 35) {
copy($newfile, file.zip) }
```

If the user visits the direct download link, the database updates the download number. How can I make the PHP run the above code without a user having to visit the download.php page?

Comment: you could use a mysql trigger i think

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what your issue is. Your php script controls the download. If it decides to transfer the file - fine. If it decides to replace the file before transfering it - also fine. _What is the issue you face?_

Comment: Could it be that you rely on static links to physical files for that "download"? Then the answer is: stop doing that! Use a php routing script for the download. The script can first evaluate prerequisites, whatever and _decide_ if a download is granted. If so, then the content of the requested file is transferred along with correct headers.

Comment: I really do rely on static links. The files should be direct download.

Comment: Sorry, but that makes zero sense. _Why_ should files be downloaded "direct"? Note that a router script does not make any visible change for the person downloading. It is just a question of whether you rely on primitive http server logic or your own script.

Comment: The files are being used as an update feature for another desktop application. The web server is meant to handle swapping out the files to ensure too many users aren't using the same keys which are included in the .zip - The desktop application can only handle direct links.

Comment: As said: there is no difference for the client side. Whether you use a "direct link" (whatever that is meant to be) or a routing script. Note: we talk about requesting a URL in both cases and receiving the response, a file.

Comment: Can you guide me in the right direction on how to set up a routing script? Thank you.

Comment: There are millions of examples for this on the internet... you make a download router script. It accepts maybe a file path as request argument (GET parameter). What it does is this: it checks if the requested file actually exists, then if a download is granted by whatever rules you want to define, then maybe choses to replace that file if you wish to, finally it sends appropriate headers (mime type and so on) and hands through the file content. That's all. That is how files are served for download these days. No reload required ;-)

Comment: I can't seem to find a good documentation on this. This was all I was able to find: http://corz.org/windows/software/Automatic-Router-Scripting-Engine/

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What you can do, if your server allows, is run a cron-job that checks intermittently if the file should be replaced. Of course you should also run the check ON the download page (so if the user selects to download a file, it will be checked if it should be replaced before it gets sent to the user).

Depending on how many times this needs to happen, a cron-job might be a bit too much, though, but again, if you can get away with checking every minute, or 5 minutes, that will work fine.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just not true. Of course you can integrate whatever logic you want into a download. The only thing to consider is that you should not use a static URL pointing directly to some physical file for a download, but to use a router script.

Comment: Well, there are multiple files that this needs to run on, and it needs to check every ~30 seconds or so.

Comment: @Arkascha - can you explain?

Comment: @user255608 I already explained that in the comments to the question itself.

Comment: @arkascha the OP asked "I am trying to check a PHP if statement without reloading the page." - as long as that if-statement is on the page he doesn't want to reload, it is not possible.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - then is there any other logical way to do this that won't take up too many resources on the server?

Comment: @arkascha is right in the other things he said - especially the answer to the OPs post. Reroute in the download.php-file, check there, and have the result sent to the user. It can be directly linked, it can call on a return-file via mod_xsendfile, it can randomly select a file from a folder - what you do in that download.php file is completely up to you.